# Regular expression for serial number matching

Tags: .net, regex

I need to write a regex expression to check if a serial number matches the following format:

XX-XXXXX-XXXXXX

Example: 50-99627-036043

A brief description of conditions:

- must be exactly 15 char long
- must only contain numbers - no letters
- dash separators at positions 2 and 8 (counting from 0)

I've generated the following with txt2re.com, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure how to debug it:

```
(\\d)(\\d)(-)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(-)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, that looks like it should work.  What language are you using and how are you checking for matches?

Comment: You're right, turns out it was an error in my code. I'll still use the below posted expressions since they look cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one dialect of regular expressions so, in the absence of knowledge as to which one you're using, it's probably best to only use constructs that they *all* usually have.

That would be:

```
^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{6}$
```

Not all regex engines will support `\d` and I've ensured you have start and end markers so that you get *exactly* the format you want (unless it matches the *entire* string, you may find it erroneously allowing stuff on either side of the 15 characters).

If, for some bizarre reason, your regex engine doesn't even support the `{m,n}`-type counts, you'll need to fully specify each digit:

```
^[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][ .... $
```

Comment: I've found \d works in c#, but are ^$ really necessary to use in this case? If there were characters added to either side, the dashes would get moved therefore failing to match the expression.

Comment: @Dr.Greenthumb, without the anchors, the regex `"abc-def"` will match that, or it may also match `"blah blah blah abc-def yada yada yada"`. The `-` char are _not_ at fixed places like 2 and 8, they're relative to the regex. Putting in anchors ensures that there is nothing on either side. You should try the accepted answer with an `X` on either side of your data (`X22-55555-666666X`). If that passes as valid with whatever method you're using (find, match, or whatever), add the anchors to ensure the length is _exactly_ 15. If that's rejected then you're using a "whole-string" matching method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I tested the previous expression with 022-55555-6666660 (added 0 to either side) and it still matched. I've made this my accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

```
\d{2}-\d{5}-\d{6}
```

Comment: On further testing, this expression matches serial numbers which are longer than 15 characters. See paxdiablo answer for more details.

Comment: Depends on whether you are using a "match" (i.e. matches the whole string) or a find (find within string).  If you use the find, then indeed you'll need to frame it with `^` and `$`.

Comment: I was using `expr.Match(productCode)`, but above expression still matched padded codes.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of the Java world and [Matcher#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()). Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: No worries, I should have mentioned that it's a C# project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
^(\d){2}\-(\d){5}\-(\d){6}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{6}
```

or

```
\d{2}-\d{5}-\d{6}
```